# Updating Hexo blog with GitHub web editor?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-pages, blogs, hexo

My blog based on Hexo is work well when I pull it to local to create a post then push it to GitHub repo, GitHub Actions will build the static pages that I newly added correctly.
But if I simply open a web editor and manually create a post in `/source/_posts`, the Actions will still run but won't build the post added by web editor.
Is it possible to update Hexo content via GitHub web editor?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You are not committing the source in a correct way, please check the github actions' log and the commit history.

Comment: But once I pull the repo that done web editor committing to local, and do some random change to then push it back to remote, the Actions will run correctly